# How to use Bluetooth with app inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I was using app inventor to build an app for a school project. The problem is I can not find a single strong tutorial on the internet of how to use Bluetooth with app inventor. I do not no much and can't give too much detail because I have now information to start with. If someone could give an example program along with how it works of point me in a direction to find some good tutorials.

Note: This is between two phones.

Comment: Didn't my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

After 2 minutes of searching on the net I have this:

1. http://appinventor.pevest.com/?p=520
2. http://puravidaapps.com/btchat.php
3. http://ai.kittywolf.net/index.php/BTChat
4. http://www.appinventor.org/Chapter12

Good luck.